# Comparing two files in Ruby with different data types

Tags: ruby

I had an interview today and wanted input on how you would solve this issue that came up.  I answered the question, but in my mind I was thinking there is a better way.

Here is the scenario.  You have two files that you need to compare.  In the first file you have a list in string format of NFL team abbreviations for example:

```
ARI
CHIC
GB
NYG
DET
WASH
PHL
PITT
STL 
SF
CLEV
IND
DAL
KC
```

In the second file you would have the following information in a hash or json for example:

```
"data":
  {"description": name: "CLEV","totfd":26,"totyds":396,"pyds":282,"ryds":114,"pen":4,"penyds":24,
"trnovr":0,"pt":4,"ptyds":163,"ptavg":36,"top":"37:05"}},"players":null}
```

How would you take the strings in the first file (the abbreviations) and see if that abbreviation was included somewhere in the data of the second file?  So, for example I want to see if CLEV, ARI, WASH, so on would be anywhere in the second file.  If that abbreviation is included I would want to extract information based on that abbreviation.

Here was my answer:
I would iterate over each abbreviation looking for that specific abbreviation inside the second file.

I felt my answer was poor, but I wanted to see if others had a good idea on what they would do.

thanks

Mike Riley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask questions in your interview.  Some questions I'd ask:

Will the hash/json include duplicate data for teams?  Meaning, will `CLEV` have multiple records in there?  If not, now you know you have unique data so there's no need to group anything ahead of time.

If it's not unique, I'd get a list of all the names that exist in the hash, so you can do a comparison between the array given and the other file.

This is in O(n) for the traversal + O(logN) for the value lookup:

```
hash =  [{'description': 'some team', 'name': 'CLEV','totfd':26,'totyds':396,'pyds':282 },
         {'description': 'some team', 'name': 'PHL','totfd':26,'totyds':396,'pyds':282 }]


hash_names = hash.map { |team| team[:name] }
```

Now that we have a list of names in the hash, we can find out where there is an overlap.  We can add the two arrays together and figure out who shows up in there more than once.  There are many ways to do that, but we should keep with our run time of O(n):

```
list = ["ARI","CHIC","GB","NYG","DET","WASH","PHL","PITT","STL","SF","CLEV","IND","DAL"]

teams_in_both = (list + hash_names).group_by { |team| team }.keep_if { |_, occ| occ.size > 1 }.map(&:first)
```

Now we have a list of:

```
["PHL", "CLEV"]
```

We know enough to say who's important to us and can fetch the remaining data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  I actually did ask quite a few questions to make sure I was getting the scenario down.  I don't care for questions like this because they are so open ended.  I do appreciate your response.